# Toggle Structure in Django-cms toolbar is Disabled

Tags: html, django, bootstrap-4, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

Problem: CMS-toolbar is hiding Navigation bar menus & it's now disabled(not moving up).
Django version = 3.0.8
Django cms = 3.8.0
I have base template and a home template. Here I am sharing base template code. What should I add to solve the issue?

```html
<!-- this is base template -->
{% load static %}
{% load cms_tags menu_tags sekizai_tags static %}  <!--load template libraries of Sekizai and CMS tag -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}"> <!-- in case you want other languages -->
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content=""> {% page_attribute "meta_description" %} <!--should have description of pages-->
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Smart Learn - {% page_attribute "page_title" %} </title> <!--In title page name should come first then website title -->

  {% render_block "css" %} <!-- loading css here render_block comes with sekizai lib to allow templates to included-->
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  {% addtoblock "css" %} <!--for sekizai tags -->
  <link href="{% static "vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"  %}" rel="stylesheet">
  {% endaddtoblock %}
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  {% addtoblock "css" %}
  <link href="{% static "css/smart-learn.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
  {% endaddtoblock %}

</head>
{% cms_toolbar %}<!--  from cms toobar -->
<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Smart Learn</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         {% show_menu 0 100 100 100 %} <!-- for cms menu -->
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="#" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="#" href="services.html">Services</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    {% static_placeholder "Footer" %}
  </footer>
  <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
  {% addtoblock "js" %}
  <script src= "{% static "vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" %}"></script>
  {% endaddtoblock %}
  {% addtoblock "js" %}
  <script src= "{% static "vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"  %}"></script>
  {% endaddtoblock %}
{% render_block "js" %} <!--to put all js template designs on home -->
</body>
</html>
```

How can I convert that icon to arrow one which can be moved up and down easily?
[This is what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv6fA.png)
[This is what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLviF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any placeholder tag inside template?

```
{% block base_content %}
  {% placeholder some_content %}

{% endblock %}
```

If not, navigation bar will be disabled.

Comment: I have base template and a home template. I do not have idea where should I put the above block code

Comment: Ok, can you take a picture of home template or check inside content tags do you have any placeholder? If not just add any like I described up, and it will work.

Comment: My home template has the code you sent which is why now toggle structure is enabled but what I want is an arrow to  be able to see menu that has been hidden under this bar.